# Turn off MySQL strict mode in docker file for Github Actions CI Build

Tags: mysql, docker, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

We've recently integrated Github Actions into our projects and are wanting to switch mysql strict mode off for the github test suite.

```
   services:
      mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        env:
          MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: yes
          MYSQL_DATABASE: github_db
        ports:
          - 3306
        options: --health-cmd="mysqladmin ping" --health-interval=10s --health-timeout=5s --health-retries=3
```

I've tried adding an extra option "sql_mode" but that didn't work:

`options: --health-cmd="mysqladmin ping" --health-interval=10s --health-timeout=5s --health-retries=3 --sql_mode=""`

I tried adding it as a command option:

`command: --sql_mode=""`

which gave the error `Unexpected value 'command'`

I've also tried adding it under variables:

```
variables:
   strict_mode: false
```

But that gave the error:

```
Unexpected value 'variables'
```

Is there a way to turn strict mode off for mysql in our docker file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no official way to do it and according to this closed issue https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/112, but I found a custom GitHub Action as a workaround: https://github.com/cweinberger/github-actions-mysql

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

1. Name the mysql container so we can reference it later. Github Actions calls `docker create` under the hood, passing in the `options` as flags. `--name` is one of the available flags, spelled out [in the docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/)

```
services:
      mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        env:
          MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: yes
          MYSQL_DATABASE: github_db
        ports:
          - 3306
        options:
          --health-cmd="mysqladmin ping"
          --health-interval=10s
          --health-timeout=5s
          --health-retries=3
          --name=somemysql
```

2. Make a new Github Actions step that runs prior to the step that runs the tests. This step [execs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) into the docker container, logs into mysql, and changes the `sql_mode`, in one line.

```
    steps:

    (some steps)

    ...

    - name: Change mysql sql_mode
      run: >
        docker exec somemysql mysql -u root -e "SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';"

    ...

    (Step that runs the tests goes here)
```